# How to write sum of fractions with powers

Tags: fractions

Disclaimer: I'm not a mathematician so this question may sound very easy to you. Sorry if this is too easy for you. 
(Also english is not my native language but I'll try.)

I have the folowing formula:
$$\frac{x*3^k}{(2n)^k}+\frac{3^{k−1}}{(2n)^k}+\frac{3^{k−2}}{(2n)^{k−1}}+...+\frac{3^{0}}{(2n)^{1}}$$
$$k \in \Bbb N,\;n \in \Bbb N,\;x \in \Bbb N$$
The question seems simple to me: How do I / Is there another way to write this formula, so I don't have the dots in the middle?
I you have any questions regarding this formula, please let me know, so I can clarify what I meant.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Should the denominator in the first term be $(2n)^{k+1}$ rather than $(2n)^k$? Also: what's the $x$ in the first term, and should it appear in any other terms as well?

Comment: @JohnHughes my formula is correct - I double checked it - the x in the first term is any real number $\frac{x*3^k+3^{k−1}}{(2n)^k}+\frac{3^{k−2}}{(2n)^{k−1}}+...+\frac{3^{0}}{(2n)^{1}}$ is maybe better to read, and the x shouldn't appear in other terms

Comment: It is unusual that the first term simply does not match the other terms. But that's okay and it does happen in legitimate problems so you have: term_that_doesn't_match+several_terms_that_do. So you leave that one term that doesn't match hanging out there, and work on notation of first_pattern_term+second_pattern_term + .... + k-th_pattern term.  The notation you want is $\sum_{i=1}^k i-th_pattern_term$. $\sum_{i=a}^n d_i$ means you have a bunch of terms and you add them all starting from $d_a$ to $d_n$. So for example, if you have $\sum_{i=0}^{10} i^2$ that would mean $0^2+1^2+2^2+... +10^2$.

Comment: This formula is actually the "result" of a recursive formula... Thats why only the first part has an x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write it as:

$\frac{x*3^k}{(2n)^k}+\frac{3^{k−1}}{(2n)^k}+\frac{3^{k−2}}{(2n)^{k−1}}+...+\frac{3^{0}}{(2n)^{1}}=$

$\frac{x*3^k}{(2n)^k}+(\frac{3^{k−1}}{(2n)^k}+\frac{3^{k−2}}{(2n)^{k−1}}+...+\frac{3^{0}}{(2n)^{1}})=$

$\frac{x*3^k}{(2n)^k}+(\frac{3^{k−1}}{(2n)^k}+\frac{3^{k−2}}{(2n)^{k−1}}+... + \frac{3^{i−1}}{(2n)^{i}}+....+\frac{3^{0}}{(2n)^{1}})=$

$\frac{x*3^k}{(2n)^k}+\sum_{i=1}^k\frac{3^{i−1}}{(2n)^i}$

In your original phrase "$\frac{x*3^k}{(2n)^k}+\frac{3^{k−1}}{(2n)^k}+\frac{3^{k−2}}{(2n)^{k−1}}+...+\frac{3^{0}}{(2n)^{1}}$" the first term does not match the rest of the others in patterns so it was isolated and written separately.

====

For the heck of it, we could write the $\frac{3^{i−1}}{(2n)^i}$ terms as $\frac 13(\frac 3{2n})^i$ so the whole thing is $\frac{x*3^k}{(2n)^k}+\frac 13\sum_{i=1}^k(\frac 3{2n})^i$ if that makes anything clearer, but we don't have to (and maybe it doesn't).

As John hughes points out in his answer $\sum_{i=1}^k(\frac 3{2n})^i$ is a geometric series and you may (or may not know)  $\sum_{i=1}^k(\frac 3{2n})^i= \frac{1-(\frac 3{2n})^{k+1}}{1-\frac 3{2n}}$ so the whole thing is $\frac{x*3^k}{(2n)^k}+\frac 13\frac{1-(\frac 3{2n})^{k+1}}{1-\frac 3{2n}}$.

But your question was about notation, not solving.

In notatation you can write $a_k + a_{k-1} + ..... + a_1$ as $\sum_{i=1}^k a_i$.

Answer (score 0):

As written, we can say 
$$
\frac{x\cdot 3^k}{(2n)^k}+\frac{3^{k−1}}{(2n)^k}+\frac{3^{k−2}}{(2n)^{k−1}}+...+\frac{3^{0}}{(2n)^{1}} = \left(\frac{x\cdot 3^k}{(2n)^k}\right) +U
$$
where 
\begin{align}
U 
&= \frac{3^{k−1}}{(2n)^k}+\frac{3^{k−2}}{(2n)^{k−1}}+...+\frac{3^{0}}{(2n)^{1}}\\
&= \frac{1}{3}\frac{3^{k}}{(2n)^k}+\frac{1}{3}\frac{3^{k−1}}{(2n)^{k−1}}+...+\frac{1}{3}\frac{3^{1}}{(2n)^{1}}\\
&= \frac{1}{3}\left( \frac{3^{k}}{(2n)^k}+\frac{3^{k−1}}{(2n)^{k−1}}+...+\frac{3^{1}}{(2n)^{1}}\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{3}\left( \left(\frac{3}{(2n)}\right)^k+\ldots + \left(\frac{3}{(2n)}\right)^1\right)\\
\end{align}
That middle thing is a geometric series, whose sum is
$\frac{\frac{3}{2n}^{k+1}}{1 - \frac{3}{2n}} - 1$, so that the whole thing is
$$
\frac{x\cdot 3^k}{(2n)^k}) + \frac{1}{3} \left( \frac{ \left(\frac{3}{2n}\right)^{k+1}}{1 - \frac{3}{2n}} - 1 \right).
$$